# Is it posible to use free form shapes as windows in OSX?

Tags: cocoa, macos, freeform

I want to use a free form shape (e.g. A partially transparent image) as a window backgound without the standard close and maximise buttons. Like the widgets do. Is that possible in OSX? I could not find any info on that or an app that uses this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can do this by subclassing NSWindow to make it borderless and transparent. You'll also subclass NSView to draw the visible custom shape, then use an instance of this view as the window's content view. The result will be a window whose only visible parts will be the shape your content view draws.

Here's a good [article with an example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html).